# How to define the initial guess for the electron density?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, density-functional-theory

This is a technical question. If I have  a one-dimensional box of length L, and an electron density existing in the box and integrating to N electrons. And if I want to determine the electron density that minimizes the energy of the system, assuming the following:

- electron density is zero at the boundary
- a fixed external potential of any kind and form
- the Thomas-Fermi kinetic energy functional is used. $v_{TF}(x)=C^{TF}*\rho^{2/3}(x)$
- absence of electron-electron interaction, $v_{HXC}(x)=0$

the question is related to the initial guess for the electron density. I've been trying the following definition for the initial $\rho(x)$

$g = \frac{l}{(gp-1.0)}$

$\rho(x)= \frac{N}{(l-g)}$

where

$g$ is the grid gap,

$gp$ is the number of grid points,

$l$ the length of the box, and

$N$ the number of electrons.

with this density, the minimized density does not preserved the number of electrons. Do you guys have any suggestion to define a suitable initial guess?

Also I am including a figure where the density at each grid point is plotted. I assumed two electrons and 200 grid points.

[image: Density at each point]

Thank you

Comment: Assumming an iterative process: I admit I never tried it, but I would think that after the first iteration, the number of electrons should be correct, and that any problems in that direction point to a problem with the iterative process, not the initial guess. In my DFT experience, I have come across qualitatively wrong solutions due to a bad guess, but never wrong electron numbers.

Comment: It's not clear to me what system are you modelling. No electron-electron interaction includes no electrostatics? What about exchange interactions which are inherent to fermions?

Comment: This is a a simple training problem where you can applied any potential. For simplicity both exchange and coulomb are assumed to be zero.
Also I added the resulting density at each grid point, it is no clear for me why the plot gets that concavity. Or maybe is correct but I am not seeing it. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Have you tried various values of l? It seems to me that the density in one dimension is trying to escape the boundaries for being in a confined box.

Comment: Is your plot of your initial guess? Then your definition of $\rho(x)$ looks strange to me:

$$\rho(x) = \frac{N}{l - g}\text{.}$$

If $N$, $l$ and $g$ are constants, where is the dependency on $x$? Your graph must be wrong. Or is it your final density that's plotted there?

Comment: Besides, can you show us your functional? It should contain a [Lagrange term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) for conservation of electrons, e.g.:

$$\min_\rho C^{TF} \rho^{\frac{2}{3}}{\left (x \right )} \\\text{subject to} \int_{0}^{l} \rho{\left (x \right )}\, dx = N$$

is equivalent to

$$\min_\rho C^{TF} \rho^{\frac{2}{3}}{\left (x \right )} - \lambda \left(\int_{0}^{l} \rho{\left (x \right )}\, dx - N\right)\text{,}$$

where $\lambda$ is a new parameter to optimise.